# Irrational elements of the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any way of identifying the irrationals in the Cantor set? For example can I prove or disprove that $\sqrt 2 -1$ belongs to the Cantor set? Can I get the irrational numbers in the Cantor set?

Cantor set contains elements which are ternary expansions involving only the digits 0 and 2. But how exactly do I get an irrational element of the Cantor set? For example the ternary.020020002... is non repeating and non terminating. But how do I get the irrational it represents? Help please.

Comment: What do you mean? If you know that elements of the Cantor set have ternary expansion with 0 and 2, then any nonrepeating expansion is irrational, which is what you are saying. So what is the issue?

Comment: In the case of $\sqrt{2}-1 = .414...$ which is removed in the first iteration of the construction.

Comment: What do you mean by "the irrational it represents"?

Comment: @JackyChong can I get its decimal form from the infinite ternary form?

Comment: @JackyChong yes. Thank you. I got it.

Comment: @EricWofsey The decimal form of the ternary is what I mean

Comment: @JackyChong Suppose it is $\sqrt 3 -1$ ? Is there any way of testing?